# Solving second order inhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have the following BVP that I am trying to solve,
$$ay^{\prime}-\epsilon y^{\prime\prime}=1$$ with $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=0$. First I solve the homogenous equation $ay^{\prime}-\epsilon y^{\prime\prime}=0$, using the characteristic equation,
$$-\epsilon r^{2}+ar=0\Rightarrow x_{1}=0, x_{2}=\frac{a}{\epsilon},$$
which gives the homogenous solution of $y_{h}(x)=c_{1}+c_{2}e^{\frac{a}{\epsilon}x}$. Now the particular solution will simply be a constant $A$. Combining the constants $c_{1}+A=c_{3}$, I get,
$$y(x)=c_{3}+c_{2}e^{\frac{a}{\epsilon}x}.$$
Now I want to apply the boundary values to determine the constants, which gives me the system of equations,
$$\begin{split}c_{3}+c_{2}&=0,\\
c_{3}+c_{2}e^{\frac{a}{\epsilon}}&=0.\end{split}$$
Solving this gives me $c_{2}=c_{3}=0$, which is of course not the solution that I want. Is there a method I can apply to not get this solution? Or did I make a mistake in my computations?

Edit: Following the comments I now consider that $y_{p}(x)=Ax$ for some constant $A$. Plugging this into the differential equation gives, the particular solution $y_{p}(x)=\frac{1}{a}x$. This gives me the solution,
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{a}x+c_{1}+c_{2}e^{\frac{a}{\epsilon}x}.$$
Now I apply the boundary conditions to get the system,
$$
\begin{split}
c_{1}+c_{2}&=0, \\
\frac{1}{a}+c_{1}+c_{2}e^{\frac{a}{\epsilon}}&=0,
\end{split}
$$
which results in $c_{1}=\frac{1}{a(e^{\frac{a}{\epsilon}}-1)}$ and $c_{2}=-\frac{1}{a(e^{\frac{a}{\epsilon}}-1)}$. So finally I get,
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{1-e^{\frac{a}{\epsilon}x}}{e^{\frac{a}{\epsilon}}-1}+x\right).$$

Comment: Thank you, I got it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this as a first order diff eq.

Make the substitution $u=y', u' = y''$ if you must.

$y' = \frac {1}{\alpha} + Ce^{\frac {\alpha}{\epsilon}x}$

And integrate $y'$

$y = \frac {1}{\alpha}x + C_1e^{\frac {\alpha}{\epsilon}x}+C_2$